# Overwrite a service using File System in C#

Tags: c#, service

I Developed two Applications :

1. Installer (Install Services )
2. Upgrade (Stop and Overwrite the Services that are already Installed)

When I run Upgrade, I m getting the Exception as

"The Process Cannot Access the File E:\TF50\SSS Service\DataModel.dll because

it is being used by another Process".

Here is my Sample Code :

```
try

{

if (xmlnode.Item(1).InnerText.ToString() != "")

{

 ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();

sc.ServiceName = "RT60Service";

           richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
           {
           richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "RT60WindowService Started" +

 " - " + DateTime.UtcNow + Environment.NewLine;

 });

if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)

sc.Stop();


fnUnZIP(xmlnode.Item(1).InnerText.ToString(), lstrHomeDirectory + 

"RT60WindowsService", "RT60WindowService");

sc.Refresh();

 if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)

{

sc.Start();

sc.Refresh();

}

richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate

{

richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "RT60WindowService Completed" + " - " + 

DateTime.UtcNow + Environment.NewLine;

richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "---------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------" + 

Environment.NewLine;

});

}

}

catch (Exception ex)

{

richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate

{

richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine;

richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "RT60WindowService Failed" + " - " + 

DateTime.UtcNow + Environment.NewLine;

richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "---------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------" + 

Environment.NewLine;

});

}

finally

{

bgworker.ReportProgress(32);

}
```

Now My Question is : 'How can we Override a Service using a filesystem??'

I got stuck here and Please help me on this ..

Comment: could you please provide more information? Which line does exception occur in?

Comment: fnUnZIP(xmlnode.Item(1).InnerText.ToString(), lstrHomeDirectory + 

"RT60WindowsService", "RT60WindowService");

Comment: please add the code to original question

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the problem is that your service is still closing down when you attempt to replace the file.

After your

```
  sc.Stop();
```

you need to wait until your service has actually stopped using the command

```
sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
```

or

```
sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
```

See
[ServiceController.WaitForStatus Method on Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.WaitForStatus(v=vs.110).aspx)